# I want to make a layout like this.I applied stroke but i do not want it on corners, like in image

Tags: android, android-layout

[image]

I do not know how to do it..tried several things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round" />


        <View
            android:layout_width="1dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary" />

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary" />


    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round" />


        <View
            android:layout_width="1dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary" />

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round" />

    </LinearLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

**OutPUT**

[image]

Comment: @Ashutosh happy to help you enjoy codding