# Recycler View custom divider for rows

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to add custom grid divider to `RecyclerView` , I have no idea please suggest some idea. For first row divider should start from beginning and for others it should be centered.

[image]

Comment: have you try any thing?

Comment: this may be help you https://stackoverflow.com/a/47428318/8112541

Comment: i can add single divider, but i have no idea to achieve above design.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [RecyclerView add divider lines only between some items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45612014/recyclerview-add-divider-lines-only-between-some-items)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [I want to make a layout like this.I applied stroke but i do not want it on corners, like in image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47428243/i-want-to-make-a-layout-like-this-i-applied-stroke-but-i-do-not-want-it-on-corne)

Comment: @Prem thanks , i will try...

Comment: @Shanmugam welcome

Comment: @Prem how can i do for recycler view row item?

Comment: @Shanmugam make that layout in your recyclerview item

Comment: @Prem i will check

Comment: @Shanmugam did you solved it

Answer (score 0):

For your solution we need to access middle column sequence `1,4,7,10...` to get that

```
if (i % 3 == 1) {
  System.out.print(i);
}
```

from this you'll get position and by that change/ add padding to line